# How to Implement SMS Verification Codes Auto Fill using React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have just started learning React-Native, I have sms verification in my demo application, my goal is to fill in the field for sms automatically when the verification code reaches the user, I use the service of a foreign company for sms sender, how is it possible to achieve all this React Native , And which package would you recommend for cross-platform device,  thank you very much.

Comment: for android you can using package sms listener, for ios idk, may you should edit at xcode

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package called **react-native-otp-autocomplete**. However, it only works for Android. There is one more npm package **react-native-otp-auto-fill**. You can check this out for IOS.